# Ffmpeg add new audio in video (mixing 2 audio)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to add an audio to video at specific duration. Now before/after that intended duration, original audio of the video should be playing; and at the intended duration only inserted audio should play.

I saw [Overlay Audio](https://superuser.com/questions/712862/ffmpeg-add-background-audio-to-video-but-not-completely-muting-the-original-audi) but it overlays over original audio. I have already tried `-itsoffset` but it mutes remaining audio.

Here is graphical description of what I want to do exactly
[image: What I want to do]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`atrim`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim), [`asetpts`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts), and [`concat`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]atrim=end=12,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aud1]; \
 [1:a]atrim=30:42,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aud2]; \
 [0:a]atrim=start=24,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aud3]; \
 [aud1][aud2][aud3]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[aout]" \
-map 0:v -map "[aout]" -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac output.mp4
```

- The first `atrim` gets the the first 12 seconds of audio from the first input (`video.mkv`).
- The second `atrim` gets seconds 30-42 from the second input (`audio.mp3`).
- The third `atrim` gets seconds 24-end of audio from the first input (`video.mkv`).
- `concat` then combines these segments into one audio stream.
- The video is [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) instead of being re-encoded in this example.
- Without `asetpts` I was getting buffer queue overflows resulting in a "jerky" output. See the [`atrim` documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim) for more info.

Comment: Thnx a lot and srry for late acceptance. :)