# Problems with joining videos in FFmpeg with a cross-fade effect (buffer queue overflow, frames dropped)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I can successfully join a couple of videos into one (using [this](https://superuser.com/a/778967/404686) method) with a nice cross-fade effect in between, but the output video contains no audio. I'm using the `-filter_complex` command.

I've managed to modify the command so that the audio would be there too, but I keep getting the *Buffer queue overflow, dropping* error while decoding. Strangely enough, the audio streams are merged correctly, with the cross-fade effect in between, while the video stream contains only a few % of the original input, due to the dropped frames. Here is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i 0.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=white:s=1920x1080
-filter_complex
"
[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=28:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=98:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+28/TB[v1];
[2:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=101:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+126/TB[v2];
[3:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=37:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+227/TB[v3];
[4:v]trim=duration=265[over0];
[0:a]afade=in:st=0:d=1,afade=out:st=28:d=1[a0];
[1:a]afade=in:st=0:d=1,afade=out:st=98:d=1,adelay=28000[a1];
[2:a]afade=in:st=0:d=1,afade=out:st=101:d=1,adelay=126000[a2];
[3:a]afade=in:st=0:d=1,afade=out:st=37:d=1,adelay=227000[a3];
[a0][a1][a2][a3]amix=inputs=4,volume=2;
[over0][v0]overlay[over1];
[over1][v1]overlay[over2];
[over2][v2]overlay[over3];
[over3][v3]overlay=format=yuv420[output]
"
-vcodec libx264 -map [output] output.mp4
```

This command produces an unusable output, with more than 90% of frames lost. The commands for the audio seem to be the problem, because when I remove them, the video is merged correctly, with no frames dropped:

```
ffmpeg -i 0.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=white:s=1920x1080
-filter_complex
"
[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=28:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=98:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+28/TB[v1];
[2:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=101:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+126/TB[v2];
[3:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=37:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+227/TB[v3];
[4:v]trim=duration=265[over0];
[over0][v0]overlay[over1];
[over1][v1]overlay[over2];
[over2][v2]overlay[over3];
[over3][v3]overlay=format=yuv420[output]
"
-vcodec libx264 -map [output] output.mp4
```

The command above gives an output containing no audio, but with all video frames in place.

I tried to use other commands for joining the audio streams, but `amix` seems to be the only one that actually works here. I've been trying to solve this for hours and I can't figure it out. Am I missing something or am I doing this whole thing wrong? Any suggestions would be welcome...

Also, here is the full console output (I removed only some of the meta-data). I quitted the encoding after receiving a bunch of "buffer queue overflow" errors, otherwise the output would be much, much larger than this:

```
>ffmpeg -i 0.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=white:s=1920x1080 -filter_complex "[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=28:d=1:alpha
=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=98:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+28/TB[v1];[2:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=
in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=101:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+126/TB[v2];[3:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=37:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-ST
ARTPTS+227/TB[v3];[4:v]trim=duration=265[over0];[0:a]afade=in:st=0:d=1,afade=out:st=28:d=1[a0];[1:a]afade=in:st=0:d=1,afade=out:st=98:d=1,adelay=28000[a1];[2:a]afade=in:st=0:d=1,af
ade=out:st=101:d=1,adelay=126000[a2];[3:a]afade=in:st=0:d=1,afade=out:st=37:d=1,adelay=227000[a3];[a0][a1][a2][a3]amix=inputs=4,volume=2;[over0][v0]overlay[over1];[over1][v1]overla
y[over2];[over2][v2]overlay[over3];[over3][v3]overlay=format=yuv420[output]" -vcodec libx264 -map [output] output.mp4
ffmpeg version N-71959-g9253cc4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-li
bass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libm
p3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --en
able-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 23.101 / 54. 23.101
  libavcodec     56. 37.102 / 56. 37.102
  libavformat    56. 32.100 / 56. 32.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '0.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
  Duration: 00:00:29.31, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 19944 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 19831 kb/s, 29.81 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 97 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2015-03-24 19:06:46
    date            : 2015-03-24T19:08:28Z
    date-eng        : 2015-03-24T19:08:28Z
    location        : █████████████████
    location-eng    : █████████████████
  Duration: 00:01:39.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 20017 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 19953 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-03-24 19:06:46
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 98 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-03-24 19:06:46
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2015-04-21 15:56:27
    date            : 2015-04-21T15:58:12Z
    date-eng        : 2015-04-21T15:58:12Z
    location        : █████████████████
    location-eng    : █████████████████
  Duration: 00:01:42.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 20020 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 19948 kb/s, 29.99 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-21 15:56:27
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #2:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 97 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-21 15:56:27
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2015-05-02 12:20:47
    date            : 2015-05-02T12:21:28Z
    date-eng        : 2015-05-02T12:21:28Z
    location        : █████████████████
    location-eng    : █████████████████
  Duration: 00:00:38.89, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 19937 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 19934 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-05-02 12:20:47
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #3:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 97 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-05-02 12:20:47
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #4, lavfi, from 'color=white:s=1920x1080':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #4:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] 264 - core 146 r2538 121396c - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 a
nalyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookah
ead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 key
int=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    encoder         : Lavf56.32.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.37.102 libvo_aacenc
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.37.102 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> format
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> afade
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> format
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> afade
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> format
  Stream #2:1 (aac) -> afade
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> format
  Stream #3:1 (aac) -> afade
  Stream #4:0 (rawvideo) -> trim
  volume -> Stream #0:0 (libvo_aacenc)
  overlay -> Stream #0:1 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_overlay_31 @ 0000000004fc3bc0] [framesync @ 0000000005173a68] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 3 times
[Parsed_overlay_31 @ 0000000004fc3bc0] [framesync @ 0000000005173a68] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[Parsed_overlay_32 @ 0000000004fc47c0] [framesync @ 000000000517d388] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 7 times
[Parsed_overlay_33 @ 0000000004fc3680] [framesync @ 000000000517d988] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 6 times
[Parsed_overlay_31 @ 0000000004fc3bc0] [framesync @ 0000000005173a68] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 9 times
[Parsed_overlay_33 @ 0000000004fc3680] [framesync @ 000000000517d988] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 9 times
[Parsed_overlay_32 @ 0000000004fc47c0] [framesync @ 000000000517d388] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 9 times
[Parsed_overlay_31 @ 0000000004fc3bc0] [framesync @ 0000000005173a68] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
[Parsed_overlay_32 @ 0000000004fc47c0] [framesync @ 000000000517d388] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
[Parsed_overlay_33 @ 0000000004fc3680] [framesync @ 000000000517d988] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
frame=   75 fps=3.6 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2425kB time=00:00:02.97 bitrate=6681.4kbits/s
video:2374kB audio:46kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.183280%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] frame I:5     Avg QP:18.75  size: 45143
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] frame P:50    Avg QP:24.25  size: 36116
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] frame B:20    Avg QP:23.56  size: 19940
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] consecutive B-frames: 49.3% 45.3%  0.0%  5.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] mb I  I16..4: 27.3% 65.2%  7.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] mb P  I16..4:  2.8% 18.9%  1.1%  P16..4: 50.6% 12.1%  3.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:10.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] mb B  I16..4:  0.5%  2.5%  0.1%  B16..8: 42.4%  7.1%  0.6%  direct: 7.0%  skip:39.6%  L0:55.9% L1:42.0% BI: 2.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] 8x8 transform intra:77.5% inter:85.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 56.3% 52.7% 2.3% inter: 30.5% 46.8% 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] i16 v,h,dc,p: 46% 10%  5% 39%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 17% 16%  5% 10%  8% 12%  6%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 22% 12%  5% 12%  8% 10%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] i8c dc,h,v,p: 61% 18% 17%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] Weighted P-Frames: Y:20.0% UV:20.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] ref P L0: 71.4% 15.5%  9.5%  3.5%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] ref B L0: 94.6%  5.4%
[libx264 @ 0000000004fa0020] kb/s:6480.80
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by audio overlapping and the reason is you haven't specified the `asetpts` for the audio explicitly. You can use something like,

```
asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]
```

Ref: [See here](https://superuser.com/questions/713633/ffmpeg-add-new-audio-in-video-mixing-2-audio)

Comment: I've already tried this (before asking here), but it didn't change anything, frames are still being dropped...